# How To Practice Back-end Dev(Django)

Tags: django

I started with web development using Django been a year now I started of doing both front-end and back-end. I then realized front-end is not my cup of tea, however I know struggle to figure out how am I too practice and improve my back-end skills without me having to first do some front-end work or its not really possible?

Where can I get online resource also to learn Python back-end(Django) I have seen many on other languages but Python none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with MDN tutorial. When you complete the tutorial you will have fair understanding of how to develop and deploy a web application - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website